# what is the corresponding of an empty tag in xml in yaml

Tags: xml, yaml, log4j2

To my knowledge these are the equivalents, but it does not work for log4j
In xml

```
    <Socket name="A1" host="localHost" port="7000">
        <SerializedLayout />
    </Socket>
```

In yml

```
   Socket: 
      name: liveSocket 
      host: localHost 
      port: 7000
      SerializedLayout: 
          null
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Log4j, but these are not equivalent data structures. In your YAML, `name`, `host`, `port`, and `SerializedLayout` are all keys in the `Socket` mapping, i.e. they're all the same kind of entity. In your XML, `name`, `host`, and `port` are attributes of `Socket`, but `SerializedLayout` is a child element—a different kind of entity entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
Socket: 
  name: liveSocket 
  host: localHost 
  port: 7000
  SerializedLayout: []
```